# GPU overheating troubleshooting

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I've been having overheating problems for a while now, and I'm not sure which part is at fault.

My specs:

- Windows 10 x64.
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Z87-HD3.
- CPU: Intel i5 4670 K.
- GPU: AMD MSI R9 290 4G Gaming.
- RAM: G.Skill Sniper 16GB [8x2] DDR3.
- Cooler: Arctic Freezer 7 Pro Rev.2.

I've got 3 fans on the case, frontal inward, upper case is inward too, and on the backside I've got an outward one.

While gaming, my GPU runs at 93-95 °C constantly, which I know is dangerously high.

I tried setting custom fan speed curve to reduce it; it's now set on MSI Afterburner on 80 °C to reach 80% and 90 °C 100% and still hits the same temps.
 The weird part is while gaming and reaching such high temps, I hear the fans getting a little louder but still pretty quiet, and from what I read online, fans at 100% should sound very loud.

Spec wise, I'm supposed to be able to even OC my hardware, but since it's getting so hot on normal stock, until I find the cause of the problem, I can't even think about that.

HWMonitor on rest:

[image]

[image]

HWMonitor after 30 minutes of playing Overwatch on Ultra [One setting below the highest].

[image]

[image]

Comment: I presume you have applied new thermal paste?

Comment: Do you think I should?
I'm no expert so I haven't concluded anything myself.